# error out if phone is not a number

Tags: mysql

If I'm creating a table such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
firstName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
phone char(20) CHECK(phone RLIKE'(?:+)?[0-9()- ]+')
);
```

If I insert something like this:

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES('joe', 'mmmm');
```

It is allowed. How do I make it throw an error if the phone does not match the regex?

Comment: pardon me if this is a silly question, but why not do this in the language you're using to connect to mysql?

Comment: Just wanted to try to do it in MySQL. I guess I'll use a trigger instead of `CHECK`